# Rebuild node form on every page refresh

Tags: caching

This question has been asked before, but the regularly accepted solution is not working for me. I want the node form to be rebuilt on every page refresh. I have added an implementation of `hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter()`, like so:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function my_module_form_node_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#cache']['max-age'] = 0;
}
```

The array inside `$form['#cache']` looks like this:

```
contexts = [
  languages:language_interface
  user.roles:authenticated
]
tags = [
  config:core.entity_form_display.node.article.default
  node:123
]
max-age = 0
```

...but the form remains cached?

Ideally, I would like to clear the node form's cache only when a new node, of a particular type, is created. When such a node is created, a new token is also generated - and it is the token tree that I want to become updated in the node form because I am adding a tokens link tree to the base of my body field widget.

```
$form['body']['tokens_tree'] = array(
  '#theme' => 'token_tree_link',
  '#token_types' => ['my_tokens'],
  '#global_types' => FALSE,
);
```

I'm assuming that invalidating the cache of the node form will achieve my goal. Certainly, doing `drush cr` does the job.

Comment: Have you tried just overwriting the whole `#cache` array key? `$form['#cache'] = ['max-age' => 0];`. You don't need the contexts and tags etc since it's not cacheable anyway.

Comment: For the second part, I think hook_entity_insert is probably too late for what you're trying to do, so best to do in the alter. What you can do to grab the bundle is `$type = $form['#node']->type;` since you're altering a node_form `#node` should always be set.

Comment: Not a direct answer to the Q, but generally speaking I think rather than trying to clear the cache yourself, or prevent it altogether, ideally you'd use a [cache tag](https://www.drupal.org/node/1884800). You say you'd like to clear the cache when a new node of a specific type is created: [there isn't a tag for specific bundles (yet)](https://www.drupal.org/node/2145751) but you _could_ use `node_list` which is used for node listings. To be more granular you could [create a custom cache tag](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/230230).

Comment: So, I removed my node type and created a custom content entity (`my_custom_entity`) to replace it. I then added `$form['#cache']['tags'][] = 'my_custom_entity_list';` to my node form alter, but no luck: my node form is not rebuilding when I update, delete or create a custom entity.

Comment: On inspecting the `X-Drupal-Cache-Tags` headers I can see `my_custom_entity_list` and `node:123`, but even when I edit _node/123_ the form does not appear to fully rebuild, not in the way it does if I do `drush cr`.

Comment: Are you invalidating the tag? If you create a custom tag you'll need to invalidate it yourself (see the link in my previous comment). Btw you don't need to change the entity type just to use custom tags.