# Permissions/access caching per node and per user

Tags: 8, users, caching

UPDATE: Narrowing this a bit. I need to, for either (a) all nodes of a given type or (b) all nodes on a specified list of node id's or (c) all users on a list of iser id's, clear the cached permissions because, due to changes not necessarily made on a given node, a user's access permission may have changed.

I have built and published a module ([Access by Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/access_by_ref)) that grants update access to nodes based on edit permissions on nodes referenced in the target node.

I am concerned that the module will not work as intended if permissions cache interferes with recognizing changes made elsewhere (eg, rights to the referenced node are changed)

What I would like to do is clear permissions caches relating to particular nodes and/or particular users or roles.  I've been studying the Cache Contexts for several days but the light bulb has not yet lit.  I'd appreciate some guidance.

Comment: Too broad, TBH. But maybe you can get some co-maintainers onboard and discuss it with them. Or maybe you can present this problem in a series of talks/discussions at a local Drupal meetup/user group.

Comment: [Implementing Custom Cache Tags](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/207444/61278) should help with what you are trying to do.

Comment: Agree with this being a bit broad. If you can find a specific set of steps that result in a problem then it might be possible to provide a specific answer on how to solve that, but this is too unspecific. This isn't a discussion forum, it's a question/answer site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access results can store cache metadata like cache tags and cache contexts. As a shortcut `AccessResult` has two specific methods to apply the correct cache metadata. Different membership in roles or a modified role results in a different set of permissions, use `cachePerPermissions()` to add a cache context for the hashed permissions. The second method is for the cache context of the current user `cachePerUser()`.

If you get field data from a node or user, add `addCacheableDependency($node)` or `addCacheableDependency($user)`.

See this example from the node module:

*core/modules/node/node.module, line 938*

```
function node_node_access(NodeInterface $node, $op, $account) {
  $type = $node
    ->bundle();
  switch ($op) {
    case 'create':
      return AccessResult::allowedIfHasPermission($account, 'create ' . $type . ' content');
    case 'update':
      if ($account
        ->hasPermission('edit any ' . $type . ' content', $account)) {
        return AccessResult::allowed()
          ->cachePerPermissions();
      }
      else {
        return AccessResult::allowedIf($account
          ->hasPermission('edit own ' . $type . ' content', $account) && $account
          ->id() == $node
          ->getOwnerId())
          ->cachePerPermissions()
          ->cachePerUser()
          ->addCacheableDependency($node);
      }
```

Comment: Okay, this is helping me move forward, and it seems to be workable for a given single node.  Here's the clarification I just added to the OP

Narrowing this a bit. I need to, for either (a) all nodes of a given type or (b) all nodes on a specified list of node id's or (c) all users on a list of iser id's, clear the cached permissions because, due to changes not necessarily made on a given node, a user's access permission may have changed.

Comment: a+b) You get a context for the node automatically, because the access is tight to a specific route with its parameters. c) `cachePerPermissions()` is very powerful, because it hashes all permissions. Use `cachePerUser()` only if the access depends on the specific user id, because this is far more expensive to cache. I think you should get with the methods I've described quite far. Important is that you add all entities (nodes, user, paragraphs, taxonomy terms ...) and config objects you use data from to calculate the access. Then test it and if you find a specific problem ask another question.

Comment: Well, I have still not figured it out.  I am stuck on what to put in as a cid.

I hacked some code and found that this is working for me now....

--------------------
  PhpStorageFactory::get('twig')
    ->deleteAll();

Comment: You don't need to think about the cache cid, this is on a lower level in the caching system. As described you deal with cache contexts and tags. Now your module returns no cache metadata at all, so you should start with the obvious I've described and test if there are any caching issues left.

Comment: Thanks for sticking with me.  Here is my concern with that code.  It appears to set the cache dependency on the $node.  Any change to the node will invalidate the cache wrt that object.  Well, that already happens, but my module changes access based on changes to OTHER nodes.  I fear it won't do the trick.  I'll check.

Comment: You have to add these OTHER nodes as well. If they are too many or nodes created in the future affect the access result, then add the cache tag node_list: `->addCacheTags(['node_list'])`. Then the access results will be recalculated for CRUD operations on any node..

Comment: Okay, so if I understand, and I am trying this, you'd have me say "
return AccessResult::allowed()
          ->cachePerPermissions()
          ->cachePerUser()
          ->addCacheableDependency($node)
          ->addCacheableDependency($control_node);"

Where $control_node is the node that has the ownership that passes thru to the targeted node.  ?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant you need to add the cacheable dependencies of all entities you get field data from. For example from a reference field in $node, to get $control_node, where you then get data from the owner field.

Comment: This appears to be working!!