# How to update route cache when saving an entity?

Tags: 8, routes, caching

I have added a custom access check to the `/user/{user}` route:

```
class RouteSubscriber extends RouteSubscriberBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function alterRoutes(RouteCollection $collection) {
    if ($route = $collection->get('entity.user.canonical')) {
      $route->setRequirement('_profile_access', '\Drupal\mymodule\Access\ProfileAccessCheck::access');
    }
  }

}
```

with some starter checks:

```
/**
 * Determines access to user profile based on conditions.
 */
class ProfileAccessCheck implements AccessInterface {

  /**
   * Checks if this profile is publicly visible.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteMatch $routeMatch
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResultAllowed|\Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResultForbidden
   */
  public function access(RouteMatch $routeMatch) {
    $requested_profile = $routeMatch->getParameter('user');
    $show_profile = (bool) $requested_profile->field_show_profile->value;

    if ($show_profile === TRUE) {
      return AccessResult::allowed();
    }

    return AccessResult::forbidden();
  }

}
```

This appears to work fine, although it seems that the "View" tab does not hide/show in the admin when saving a user. If I clear the site cache, the tab is there on a user edit (or not, depending on value). Is there a way to get it to bind to the user or is it not worth while?

Comment: You need to add the correct cache dependencies to the returned access result, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/268388/permissions-access-caching-per-node-and-per-user/

Comment: Thanks, just saw that in one of the core tests!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out I just had to chain it to the `AccessResult` like so:

```
AccessResult::allowed()->addCacheableDependency($requested_profile);
```

Same for `forbidden()`. Now the 'View' tab is visible appropriately.